# Run cron on last monday of the month - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-5.3

I want to run a cron **only on last Monday of the month** using Laravel's Cron API. I have checked this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

I don't get any solution there.

At most I can:

```
$schedule->command(Commands\PerformerReminder::class)->monthly()->mondays();
```

But I think it will run the cron on each Monday of the month, not just on the **last Monday**.

If that is not possible using Laravel's cron API, them I'm fine with using regular cron options.

I think that will be like this:

```
$schedule->command(Commands\PerformerReminder::class)->cron('* * * * *);
```

I don't know what will be the value inside cron() function.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks,

Parth Vora

Comment: have you tried `->when(Closure);`?

Comment: oh yes. I completely oversight that option. Let me try that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that working with this:

**App/Console/Kernal.php:**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule
        ->command(Commands\PerformerReminder::class)
        ->when(fn() => Carbon::parse('last monday of this month')->isToday());
}
```

Comment: `return $lastmonday->isToday();` is enough

Comment: `return new Carbon('last monday of this month')->isToday();` is even shorter :)

Comment: Or even `Carbon::parse` if you don't want to have to surround `new Carbon`with parentheses. And you can use arrow functions in php8 so it's 1 line without return, makes the code very readable

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
use Carbon;

$schedule->command(Commands\PerformerReminder::class)->mondays()->when(function(){
    // return true if this monday is last monday of this month

    return (Carbon::now()->isSameDay($now->lastOfMonth(Carbon::MONDAY)));
});
```